# PDFs in R or Excel for multiple excel sheets with three different variables

Tags: r, vba, excel

I am a learner of R who has an excel file with multiple sheets of a month spanning 30years. Each sheet has 3 variables and 17 columns (shown below). I am trying to find the probability density function (PDFs) of each variable in each sheets. Example is this, at the first height (bold) for each sheet, I want the PDF, and the second height, third height and so on. 
The same goes for the Direction as well as the Velocity.

Is this possible in R? or even Excel?

```
         Sheet1                     Sheet2                          Sheet3
 Height Direction Velocity  Height Direction Velocity     Height Direction Velocity
   **147**  304       2.3       141**   336      2.2      **148**   320      1.4
    800     308       2.8       797     351      2.4        806     330      1
    1500    310       4.1       1503    335      2          1515    293      0.4
    3077    308       9.3       3096    293      4.2        3112    315      1
    4299    309       14.1      4325    296      6.4        4342    333      3.3
    5704    308       18.9      5733    295      8.4        5753    333      5.7
    7361    308       23.6      7388    299      10.5       7409    331      7.9
    9388    309       29.1      9404    306      13.3       9425    330      10.4
    10610   310       31.1      10616   305      14.6       10638   323      11.5
    12051   308       31        12051   301      15         12072   309      12.4
    13855   302       27        13853   291      14.3       13874   293      12.6
    16354   299       16.3      16352   282      10.8       16374   280      8.7
    18549   294       9.2       18552   283      7.7        18572   278      5.2
    20643   289       5.8       20649   275      6.2        20670   281      4.8
    23860   264       6         23891   260      5.9        23896   269      7.3
    26471   267       10.6      26504   269      8.5        26505   269      12.1
    31004   245       17.5      31055   262      11.9       31050   254      17.7
```

How do I go about this in R or Excel? I would like someone to point me in the right direction.
Thanks to all.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  The second argument, `sheet`, could be referring to the `sheetIndex` argument or it could be referring to the  `sheetName` argument but there is no way to tell which was wanted since they both abbreviate to `sheet`.  See `?read.xlsx` for more info.

Comment: okay but the probability density function is the one I am mostly interested in. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `density` function.

Taking your data as an example:

```
df <- read.table(text="Height Direction Velocity  Height Direction Velocity     Height Direction Velocity
     147    304       2.3       141     336      2.2        148     320      1.4
    800     308       2.8       797     351      2.4        806     330      1
    1500    310       4.1       1503    335      2          1515    293      0.4
    3077    308       9.3       3096    293      4.2        3112    315      1
    4299    309       14.1      4325    296      6.4        4342    333      3.3
    5704    308       18.9      5733    295      8.4        5753    333      5.7
    7361    308       23.6      7388    299      10.5       7409    331      7.9
    9388    309       29.1      9404    306      13.3       9425    330      10.4
    10610   310       31.1      10616   305      14.6       10638   323      11.5
    12051   308       31        12051   301      15         12072   309      12.4
    13855   302       27        13853   291      14.3       13874   293      12.6
    16354   299       16.3      16352   282      10.8       16374   280      8.7
    18549   294       9.2       18552   283      7.7        18572   278      5.2
    20643   289       5.8       20649   275      6.2        20670   281      4.8
    23860   264       6         23891   260      5.9        23896   269      7.3
    26471   267       10.6      26504   269      8.5        26505   269      12.1
    31004   245       17.5      31055   262      11.9       31050   254      17.7", header=TRUE)
```

Now applying the function `density` to each column:

```
densities <- lapply(df, density)
```

Plotting the first height density and superimposing the other two heights (they are all pretty much the same):

```
plot(densities[[1]], main = "height")
lines(densities[[4]], col="red")
lines(densities[[7]], col="blue")
```

[image]